# How to overlap images in react-native

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm interested in creating a custom badge on top of an avatar (profile image), except I can't seem to get images to overlap. I tried using a 'translateY' style transform but it is ignored and the two images are still placed side by side, flex box style, even though I want them to overlap. Note, I'm using Views in the example, but I imagine Images work the same way.

```
'use strict';

var React = require('react-native');
var {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
} = React;

var SampleApp = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.avatar} />
        <View style={styles.badge} />
      </View>
    );
  }
});

var styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
  },
  avatar: {
    backgroundColor: 'black',
    width: 60,
    height: 60,
  },
  badge: {
    backgroundColor: 'red',
    width: 20,
    height: 20,
    translateY: -60,
  },
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('SampleApp', () => SampleApp);
```

Comment: Eric Anderson you should mark a response as the accepted answer.  The answer from Raj looks right to me.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I review your code and make some changes to get your expected output.
The updated code is:-

```
'use strict';
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
var React = require('react-native');                                                                                                                                                                                 
var {                                                                                                                                                                                                                
  AppRegistry,                                                                                                                                                                                                     
  StyleSheet,                                                                                                                                                                                                      
  Text,                                                                                                                                                                                                            
  View,                                                                                                                                                                                                            
} = React;                                                                                                                                                                                                           
                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
var SampleApp = React.createClass({                                                                                                                                                                                  
  render: function() {                                                                                                                                                                                             
    return (                                                                                                                                                                                                     
      <View style={styles.container}>                                                                                                                                                                      
        <View style={styles.avatar}>                                                                                                                                                                         
          <View style={styles.badge} />                                                                                                                                                                        
        </View>                                                                                                                                                                                              
      </View>                                                                                                                                                                                              
    );                                                                                                                                                                                                           
  }                                                                                                                                                                                                                
});                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
var styles = StyleSheet.create({                                                                                                                                                                                     
  container: {                                                                                                                                                                                                     
  },                                                                                                                                                                                                               
  avatar: {                                                                                                                                                                                                        
    backgroundColor: 'black',                                                                                                                                                                                    
    width: 60,                                                                                                                                                                                                   
    height: 60,                                                                                                                                                                                                  
  },                                                                                                                                                                                                               
  badge: {                                                                                                                                                                                                         
     backgroundColor: 'red',                                                                                                                                                                                      
     width: 20,                                                                                                                                                                                                   
     height: 20,                                                                                                                                                                                                  
     left: 20,                                                                                                                                                                                                    
     top: 20,                                                                                                                                                                                                     
  },                                                                                                                                                                                                               
});                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
AppRegistry.registerComponent('SampleApp', () => SampleApp);
```

See the change in above code snippet.
Output screenshot link:- https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_8x_Jy7Ac9bbDh1eHhfelJpSmc/view?usp=sharing

Whenever you want to override any react component simply put that component in between start and close of another component.
For example:-

If you want to overlap one image on another then use tags like

```
    <Image source={require('image!firstimage')} style={..}>
      <Image source={require('image!secondimage')} style={..}>
    </Image>
```

Comment: This answer is supported by the examples used in the RN docs: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/image.html#examples

Comment: Know of any way to save the resulting parent-image to a file? The use case is to add 'stickers' to the users' images and then upload the result

Comment: As of 20th of may 2018 the above method isn't supported.

Comment: This doesn't work anymore in 2020. Use css absolute positioning instead

Answer (score 3):

Nesting `Image` components doesn't work anymore. What you could use is `ImageBackground` instead or absolute positioning.

As doc says you can code your own specific component by checking the source code of `ImageBackground`
https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/Libraries/Image/ImageBackground.js